# White smoke (lots) from 95 4Runner tailpipe

Tags: oil, oil-leak, smoke, 4runner

I have a SEVERE oil leak on my 95 4Runner (v6 3VZE). I put a quart in every day or two. Yesterday I felt she needed extra love so I put in two quarts. Now she's billowing huge plumes of white gray smoke on startup and acceleration with no hint of quitting.

There's no way it could have been OVER filled as there was only about a quart +/-  in it before I added to it. Should mention that a few days ago a buddy put ten gallons of "older" gas in my tank and she's been running like crap since, but no snow till now.

In an attempt to counteract the possibility of overfilment and burning oil rather than gas I immediately filled the rest of the tank (about half) with high grade chevron techron. Didn't make a difference.

The oil leak is so bad (rear main seal) that her undercarriage is completely blackened and caked  with oil making it look like  she's leaking from like 10 different places. However, I’m pretty sure it’s ONLY three .

Any Advice for this girl who ❤️s her runner but is clueless when it comes to the many maladies that  plague her??? (Pretty positive Not a head gasket issue, which have already been replaced twice.)

Comment: If you over-fill the oil (say, by adding two quarts), the excess can easily get blown through the exhaust. If you REALLY over-fill it, the crankshaft will whip the oil into a foam, which doesn't lubricate very well (at all), and your engine will seize. Also, you can't tell how much oil is in the pan just by looking at the dipstick. Even if the stick was dry, there can still be a few quarts in the pan. The dipstick is just meant to give you a "high or low" indication. It doesn't bottom out at the bottom of the pan.

Comment: White smoke is an indication of "water" in your system. It's highly possible that some coolant found it's way into the combustion chamber. You could have a faulty gasket, warped head, etc. Even the the old gas, could have some water, which will drop to the bottom of the tank. As you said, your 4runner is running like "crap" after pouring old gas, so I'm betting my socks that you fuel pump is sucking a mixture of gas and water, which in turn makes a bad combustion and white smoke.